# Договор оферта на русском для вывода денег в русские банки из Apple

Tags: apple, юридические-аспекты

Как выводятся деньги в предприятие зарегистрированное в России (на счет русского банка) из Apple?

Бухгалтеру нужна публичная договор оферта Apple на русском языке. Т.е. основание, на котором Apple переводит деньги на счет организации разработчика.

Я нашел только это на английском:

https://www.apple.com/legal/procurement/docs/OL-APAC-AP_v.1.0.pdf

https://download.developer.apple.com/Documents/license_agreements__ios_standard/ios_program_standard_agreement_20130610.pdf

Есть ли договор оферта на русском языке?

И если где-то есть описание вывода денег с документами, то буду очень благодарен за ссылочку.

Answer (score 2):

Перевод договора с Apple

http://www.it-lex.ru/it-pravo/pervod-apple-developer-program-license-agreement-schedule2/

английская версия

https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/da/jumpTo?page=contracts  (кнопка Download Agreement)